# How to add a clickable question mark to select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add a clickable question mark to the right side of the select option the  or  tag but I'm not having any luck. I tried using content in css but the positions are off and I can't add a link and I tried using several options in the body to no luck. Can this be done and if so, how?

Here's the select option:
http://jsbin.com/xehozufe/1/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You just want a linked "?" next to the `select`?

Comment: Oh, you want it next to the `<option>`, inside the drop down list. Yeah, that's not going to happen. You would need to create a custom menu.

Comment: @dg988 there's nothing I can include in the css to accomplish this?

Comment: Nope. Like you said, you can get text in there, but there's no way to link it. You could add a `title` attribute that would pop up on hover of the `option`, or add a javascript handler to show/do something when an `option` is selected.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do fits with the component vocation, the best thing I can think is to update your question mark next to your select box when an option is selected, otherwise, I would suggest you to have an explicit list with entries each decorated with a question mark.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can use

```
$("#selBox").attr('size', value);
```

Please check the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ankitjc/FcYpL/1/).** Something on these lines?